# IBM Cloud App Services not working

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am working on a Windows 10 home machine. I needed to use the IBM cloud web app services . I created a starter kit for expressjs backend and added a Watson discovery service resource.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the prerequisites documentation all the way from installing developer tools to downloading app.I opened it in webstorm.

When I "Build app in release mode" in Webstorm I get the following error :

```
An error error during connect: Post http://%!F(MISSING)%!F(MISSING).%!F(MISSING)pipe%!F(MISSING)docker_engine/v1.30/build?buildargs=%!B(MISSING)%!b(MISSING)x_dev_user%3A%!r(MISSING)oot%2C%!b(MISSING)x_dev_userid%3A%22%!D(MISSING)&cachefrom=null&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile-tools&labels=null&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=expressjsbackend-express-tools&target=&ulimits=null: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. was encountered while building the Docker image.
```

How can I rectify this ?

Please help!

Comment: Which steps did you follow, what is the URL? That seems like your Webstorm environment is not configured.

Comment: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/apps/tutorials/tutorial_web.html#before-you-begin


I followed these steps

Comment: Those instructions say to use the IBM Cloud dev tool to build the app, not the IDE (Webstorm). Did you follow those steps...?

Comment: Yes, I followed those steps. I chose Webstorm as my IDE ...And I got the error :(

Comment: So, did you build the app as stated in the instructions? Do not use Webstorm to build the app.

Comment: I thought building the app is done by importing the settings.jar file(which was given in the developer tools in step 1 ) into webstorm which gives the "IBM App Developer tools > Build app in release mode " option. 

Because this wasn't working , I tried using  the python-django app instead and I tried building it in pycharm... I get the following error now : 

Building...
OK
Creating a container named 'pythondjango-django-tools' from that image...
FAILED
An error Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /app was encountered while creating Docker container 'pythondjango-django-tools'.

Comment: Hi Kiera.  I saw your other question and posted an "answer" looking for some more details.  From the error here, it is definitely pointing to Docker -- note that the message is ultimately that it cannot find the Docker daemon.  If you have Docker for Windows installed, you'll need to make sure it is started first.

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately I have a Windows 10 home which restricts me to Docker Toolbox . Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kiera commented above, unfortunately Docker for Windows is not available on Windows 10 Home edition.  This link from the Docker forum confirms this as well:  https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home/11722

IBM Cloud Developer Tools, including IDE integrations, require Docker for Windows and so is not available for use with Windows 10 Home edition.

Comment: So I temporarily managed a machine with a docker which is successfully building the app. I do however need help at multiple instances of my project. Could you pleaseee have a look at another question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446804/how-to-connect-the-back-end-and-the-front-end-and-use-the-discovery-api-in-ibm-c